# How do you use echo in php to print text in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to use php to print out a line of text onto a html file, but when I run the html, it merely prints the word undefined. How can I fix this? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var textinhtml=document.createElement("div");
var text=document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mikeyrichards.bugs3.com/test.php",true));
textinhtml.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(textinhtml);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World"
?>
```

Comment: Your usage of XMLHttpRequest is wrong, especially when performed in asynchronous mode, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You do know that the php file needs to have <?php before any executable php code?

Comment: I believed that the only was true when included directly into the html. Thanks.

Comment: the error is a javascript one, not a php one

Comment: @Mikey @rivimey is right, even if you are not including in html your php code must be enclosed in `<?php ?>` delimiters

Comment: @dvhh thanks, though in php circles it's considered best not to include the trailing ?> unless you have more literal text following. That is, if you have a file just containing php code, you don't have a terminator. This is to avoid unexpected text in the output -- eg from blank lines -- that mess up other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented your usage of `XMLHttpRequest` is wrong, you should check online example of it, like [this example from the mozilla dev network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Adapted to your script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onload = function() {
       var textinhtml=document.createElement("div");
       var text=document.createTextNode(this.responseText);
       textinhtml.appendChild(text);
       document.body.appendChild(textinhtml);
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mikeyrichards.bugs3.com/test.php",true)
   xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

this script does not account for the **errors from the request**. Please read the documentation to handle them.

Comment: That code got the data to show up, but it also brought in a whole bunch of comments from the serving domain. The code will work for now but I may need more help later.

Comment: as I am assuming that you want to do a cross-domain xhr request you should read about [ cors http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ ] or JSONP request